# Is there a "Desktop Dapp"?

Tags: contract-design, dapps, architecture

The most of "decentralized applications" are a "web" application as follows :

```
Front End (usually JavaScript) => Smart Contract (usually Solidity) => Blockchain (usually Ethereum)
```

**Is this the only schema of a Dapp?** And if there is other schema, could you describe another schema of a Dapp?

Comment: I love this question because it recognizes something very significant about decentralized applications. They need a browser. Other than the node itself, which needs to get its data, they don't even need the internet. I envision purely desktop dApps that get all of their data through the chain. Who cares if it's currently impractical. Think about what the apps would be like if they didn't need the web to communicate directly.

Comment: You can already embed data from the chain into any regular software without the need for a browser, simply query it through the RPC interface of your favourite node client.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the the [Mist Browser](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) is trying to be something in between: A standalone app for browsing dApps and thus making then feel a little like a desktop application.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate a bit more detailed explain :) Thanks.

Comment: What questions remain about the Mist Browser ?

Comment: I mean is there ex. an article to explain how Mist browser can do this ? Because imagine how a browser can work like a desktop application is interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use electron.js. I haven't tried it  yet. [Here's a link to it](https://www.electronjs.org/)